# BotFramework: Slack ignores new ConversationId

Tags: botframework, slack

Scenario: My bot needs to be able to update users about status changes of items. 
The suggested flow according to [BotFramework docs](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/routing.html#conversation)
is to use CreateDirectConversation to obtain a conversation id from the channel. We store some data about the product in the serialized LuisDialog and send a message to the user.

Sending a message to the user works like a charm on both Skype and Slack, but the users reponse does not end up in the dialogs Resume method when using Slack.
On CreateDirectConversation Skype seems to simply return the id of the existing conversation which works fine, but Slack returns a different id following the format "USER-ID:channel-id:some-internal-id"

The problem seems to be that Slack sends the users response to our message using a different conversation id "BOT-ID:channel-id:same-internal-id". The dialog state of our bot including the data is obviously stored using the conversation id we got in CreateDirectConversation. 
Result is that the users response ends up in our dialog as unknown Intent :/

Does anyone have/had the same issue and what could be potential fixes?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in the Slack channel (CreateDirectConversation is returning an incorrectly formatted ConversationId).  We'll get a fix ready and it will go live the next time we deploy - probably later this week.